# Проблема с датасетом mnist

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Вроде как проблема в том, что у меня загружаемое изображение (28,28,3) а мне надо (28,28,1)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab import files
from keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow import keras 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten 
import cv2
from PIL import Image
```

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

```
x_train = x_train / 255
x_test = x_test / 255
```

```
y_train_cat = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test_cat = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)
```

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
loss='categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train_cat, batch_size=32, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2)
```

```
img_height = 28
img_width = 28
```

```
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test_cat)
```

```
files.upload()
```

```
img = tf.keras.utils.load_img('Безымянный.png',target_size=(img_height, img_width))
img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, 0)


predictions = model.predict(img_array)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])


print(
    "Это изображение скорее цифра {} с {:.2f} процентной вероятностью."
    .format([np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
)
```

Писал все в google colaboratoty, выдает ошибку:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_1" (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784, but received input with shape (None, 2352)
    
    Call arguments received by layer "sequential_1" (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 28, 28, 3), dtype=float32)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, попробуйте загрузить картинку в ч/б режиме:

```
img = tf.keras.utils.load_img('Безымянный.png',
      target_size=(img_height, img_width), color_mode="grayscale")
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло